# Make SEO sensitive URL (avoid id) Zend framework

Tags: php, zend-framework, url, seo

i have url like this :

```
http://quickstart.local/public/category1/product2
```

and in url (category1/product2) numbers are id , categorys and products fetched from database attention to the id

id is unique

i need to the sensitive url like zend framework url. for example :`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/621380/seo-url-structure`

how i can convert that url to the new url like this

is there any way?!!

Comment: just a note - product url (for eshop) should not contain category, as it can change and then it would either not make any sense or change the url, thus destroying any backlinks ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use ZF's [Zend_Controller_Router_Route](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.standard). For example, to make similar url to those used by SO, one could define a custom route in an application.ini as follows (assuming you have controller and action called questions and show respectively):

```
resources.router.routes.questions.route = '/questions/:id/:title'
resources.router.routes.questions.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route" 
resources.router.routes.questions.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.questions.defaults.controller = questions
resources.router.routes.questions.defaults.action = show
resources.router.routes.questions.defaults.id = 
resources.router.routes.questions.defaults.title = 
resources.router.routes.questions.reqs.id = "\d+"
```

Having such a route, in your views you could generate an url as follows:

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('id'=>621380,'title' => 'seo url structure'),'questions');
// results in: /myapp/public/questions/621380/seo+url+structure

//OR if you really want to have dashes in your title:

<?php echo $this->url(array('id'=>621380,'title' => preg_replace('/\s+/','-','seo url structure'),'questions');
// results in: /myapp/public/questions/621380/seo-url-structure
```

Note that  `/myapp/public/` is in the url generated because I don't have virtual hosts setup on my localhost nor any modifications of .htaccess made. Also note that you don't need to have unique `:title`, because your real id is in `:id` variable.

As a side note, if you wanted to make it slightly more user friendly, it would be better to have your url as `/question/621380/see-url-structure` rather than `/questions/621380/see-url-structure`. This is because under this url you would have only one question, not many questions. This could be simply done by changing the route to the following `resources.router.routes.questions.route = '/question/:id/:title'`.

EDIT:

And what to do with categories and products that you have in your question? So, I would define a custom route, but this time using [Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.regex):

```
resources.router.routes.questions.route = '/questions/(\d+)-(d+)/(\w*)'
resources.router.routes.questions.type = "Zend_Controller_Router_Route_Regex" 
resources.router.routes.questions.defaults.module = default
resources.router.routes.questions.defaults.controller = questions
resources.router.routes.questions.defaults.action = show
resources.router.routes.questions.map.1 = category
resources.router.routes.questions.map.2 = product
resources.router.routes.questions.map.3 = title
resources.router.routes.questions.reverse = "questions/%d-%d/%s"
```

The url for this route would be then generated:

```
<?php echo $this->url(array('category' => 6213,'product' => 80,'title' => preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', 'seo url structure')),'questions' );    ?>
// results in: /myapp/public/questions/6213-80/seo-url-structure
```

Hope this will help or at least point you in the right direction.

Comment: @afsane. One reason may be urlencode function. url helper is using it to encode your strings. You can switch it off by setting last url helper's parameter to false, e.g. `$this->url(array('category' => 6213,'product' => 80,'title' => preg_replace('/\s+/', '-', 'seo url structure')),'questions', false, false);`  The third parameter's value is false by default, however the forth's parameter value is true by default. Maybe this will help.

Comment: this answer was realy nice, thanx a lot.
but i have a prob, when title showed characters convert to the unknow characters like this %231607%3B%26%231608%3B%26%23157
language that saved in db is persian with utf8 . when i use of just echo function every things is ok but when i use of $this->url function characters have prob

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to store a unique value in your database with a field name such as 'url' or something similar. Every time you generate a new product you will have to create this unique url and store it with the product information. A common way to do this is to take the name of the product and make it url friendly:

```
public function generateUrl($name)
{
    $alias = str_replace(' ', '-', strtolower(trim($name)));
    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9-]/', '', $alias);
}
```

Calling this method:

```
$url = $this->generateUrl("My amazing product!");
echo $url;
```

will output:

my-amazing-product

You'll need to check that the output from this function does not already exist in the database as you will use this value to query on instead of the id.

If you apply this logic to the categories as well, you can have easily readable and descriptive urls like the one below. You may need to tweak your routing before this works correctly though.

http://quickstart.local/public/awesome-stuff/my-amazing-product